# Uniquely identify an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 and their databases

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, instance, uniqueidentifier

I need to get the value, the best `GUID`, to uniquely identify an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 and to uniquely identify a specific database on the server.

As for the specific database, I think that I can use `[master].[Sys].[Master_files]` and column `file_guid`, but I don't know where I can find similar information about the instance of SQL Server 2008R2.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do? It isn't obvious what your goal is or how a GUID would help. All databases are already uniquely named: `Server\Instance.Database` where `\Instance` is optional, and even if you have a GUID you'll still have to map it to a name to do anything useful with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `file_guid` of the data file for the master database. It's very unlikely to ever change for a given instance and because its a GUID it is unique.

---

Sorry, forgot about that. Than there is no identifier accessible to T-SQL (that I know of).
You could create your own and store it either in an extended property somewhere in master or, using xp_regread somewhere in the registry. I assume you are looking for some kind of license control. If that is correct, the registry is probably your best bet.

Comment: For the master database this field is null, so can I update this field by new guid?